# HTML how to make a button unclickable just using html?

Tags: html, button, click

Is there a quick, possible way to do a button unclickable? To be exact, its an  tag, not a  tag. Thanks!

```
<input type="submit" value="Blocked" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) Boolean attribute

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input type="submit" value="Enabled" class="btn btn-success" />
<input type="submit" value="Disabled" class="btn btn-success" disabled />
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried enabled="false" but it did not work.. This is perfect however. Thanks!

Comment: @RickAstley If this answered your question, don't forget to [approve the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - Thank you